# How to position a footer/element relative to the bottom of the page?

Tags: css, sticky-footer, css-position

I'm trying to position my footer in the bottom of the page but with little success.

I can only paste the link as there is a lot of CSS in there and I'm not sure where is my problem.

So this is the link: [Test](http://rolandgroza.com/projects/roland/) ; If someone would like to help me out I would appreciate it.

**EDIT**: The question is old and the url is not there anymore, but the answer may be considered valid anyway when an individual needs to position a footer (or any other element) to the bottom of the page (so called *sticky footer*).

Comment: Script: https://raw.github.com/chaoscod3r/less.js/master/dist/less-1.3.0.min.js:9 , Firefox crashed, asked me to stop the said script.

Comment: There's a fallback for that, to load locally. Try in a few minutes, my server might act up as I just uploaded the files.

Comment: This is a good example of why all the relevant information should be included in the question, not referenced by links. Yes, the answers could be useful, but the question is very vague. If you edit the question to make it more meaningful I'll give you a reopen vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have actually used [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) solution lately. It works very well. And if you have dynamic content inside the footer you can easily make a script which on resize or orientation change changes the height of the footer and the margin on the body.

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; //same height as the margin to the bottom of the body
}
```

Comment: Note that your question was hijacked by someone else turning it into a completely different question. I have since reversed that change, as it was not made in good faith. You may want to clarify if your answer applies to the original question as well.

Comment: @BoltClock ~ I've noticed that, but I could not figure it out how he/she did that, neither I could revert back or deny his/hers changes. Thanks for doing that :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#footer {
      margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Remove that from #footer {} definition. Also, since you want it relative, you'll have to increase the height of the div above the footer, till it reaches the end of screen. Otherwise you'll have to use absolute positioning.

Edit : Also remove "position: relative" from #footer

Edit 2: Posting all the definitions I see on firebug.

```
footer {
    background-image: url("http://rolandgroza.com/projects/roland/assets/less/../gfx/background-light.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

footer {
    background-image: url("http://rolandgroza.com/projects/roland/assets/less/../gfx/background-light.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

footer {
    display: block;
}
```

And you may delete the 1st set of definitions and the last with "display:block" . If you can find them somewhere.

Comment: Same thing, I don't think it's because of that

Comment: @Roland , also remove "position: relative" from #footer. With these 2 changes I said, the footer went right down. [tested using firebug]

Comment: I don't see why removing the `position: relative;` would fix it :) Just take a look at this article : http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/.

Comment: Ok I see why it's working. you have 2 different #footer definition, and the "position: relative" one is taking higher priority. When you disable it, the "position: absolute; bottom: 0" is applied. First definition at line 2581 and 2nd at line 3119

Comment: I'm using media queries, perhaps that's what you're seeing. Depends on the screen size, try resizing the browser :)

Comment: I suggest you start using firebug ( firefox extension ). Things like these will be 10x easier to spot using it. [Better than the dev tools of the rest of the browsers]

Comment: I'm using Chrome, it's console, and Firebug Little.

Comment: All right, like I said, I can see 2 different definitions of #footer, and one of them has " position: relative", when disabled that property, the problem you have is fixed.

Comment: I'm looking for it but I cannot see it :|

Comment: I've added the code I see on firebug, hope you'll be able to trace it.

Comment: That's weird, because I have nothing like that in my CSS, perhaps it's  because of the media queries. I'll try adding the same thing to all the MQs. Hope it'll fix it. I also have another problem, if you look carefully at the content on the HOME page, you'll see that the heading are distanced a lot, they're supposed to be right under the header, but there's a big space there about 70px I thing, and I also cannot see where the problem appears, can you take a brief look  ?

Comment: Or you can add "position: absolute !important;" if you are unable to trace. Btw, all your elements have 2 different definitions, you better check that out and fix, before fixing other things.

Comment: What to do if position relative div was dynamic size?

Comment: @Kermani could you please post a new question or provide a link to your current page where this is required.

Answer (score 2):

Use css tables:

**[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sX9Nk/)** - little content

**[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sX9Nk/3/)** - little content + large footer

**[FIDDLE3](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sX9Nk/4/)** - lots of content

### Markup

```
<header class="row">header content</header>
<div class="row">content here</div>
<footer class="row">footer content</footer>
```

### CSS

```
html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    }
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
.row {
    display:table-row;
    background:orange
}
div.row {
    height:100%;
    background:pink
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, please explain what was my problem?

Comment: Sorry, but the question you answered for the bounty was a completely different question from the original. Unfortunately we can't migrate answers across questions, and I don't want to take away the bounty which you worked for. I will let you decide if you want to keep the answer for the bounty, or if you want to remove your answer.

Comment: Also see the comment I just left for the [original asker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470241/how-to-relative-position-the-footer-in-the-bottom-of-the-page#comment38250856_23442814).

Answer (score -4):

Try adding

```
.footerClass {
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;
}
```

to your css file and add the class footerClass to your footer-tag

Comment: Yeah, I'm using that now, but I want to position it relative, because of the content which will be responsive and a vertical overflow might show up.

Comment: So you want the footer to stay stay "above" the content which might overflow underneath the footer, so the footer is always visible?

Comment: I can make it stay above the content with an `z-index`, what I want is the content to push the footer down, and the content to be always 100% tall, so that it pushes the footer in the bottom of the page no matter what's inside the content.

Comment: Okay, I would still go with absolute-positioning, but I would also position the content to be 50px above bottom and whatever space you need from the top (position:absolute;bottom:50px;top:50px;)

Comment: Well, already doing that on my localhost. Seems like there's no way around, I can only use absolute positioning.